# Some more text showing up on console after debugging on VS 2017 Community

Tags: c++, console, visual-studio-2017

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to see only "Hello World" on the console after debugging. However, I see more stuff that distracts me, how can I fix that?
IMAGE: 
http://prntscr.com/lt9jud

Comment: That's output from Visual Studio. If you run your program in a stand-alone command-line window it won't be there. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Part of that output is because the Visual Studio debug windows used to vanish instantly when the program ended leading to millions of posts (here and elsewhere on the Internet) from panicked beginning programmers who thought their program had crashed, failed to run, or been eaten by a Grue.

Comment: I'm not showing any image at the link.  Could you paste the screen snapshot into your question or better, the text into your question.

Comment: Tried to paste the image in, but somehow it crashed my browser. Won't be trying again.